# Why is exception displaying as a number?

Tags: python, python-2.7, try-catch

I have a Python script running on a schedule and I have set up a `try/except` block to catch all exceptions and email me the exception message so that I can be made aware that something has gone wrong.

I am observing some odd behavior. For every execution of my script, an Exception is being caught where the message is simply:

`93`

This content is the same when I print it to the console as well.

When I remove the `try/except` block, there aren't any exceptions being thrown by my code. Does anyone know why the presence of the `try/except` blocks are causing exceptions and why it is just returning digits?

```
try:

    #do something

except Exception as ex:
    s = smtplib.SMTP('000.000.000.000',25)
    s.starttls()
    s.sendmail('email@email.com', 'email@email.com', 'General Exception in final_parse method       ' + str(ex.message))
    print str(ex.message)
    s.quit()
```

Comment: To give more details, print just `ex` and see results...

Comment: What's in the `try` block? We can't debug code we can't see.

Comment: To get even more info, `import traceback` and on exception, `print traceback.format_exc()`. I'm not sure how the exception doesn't exist without `try`/`except` so it's useful to see the traceback

Comment: You only print the exception `message`, not the entire message (that will also contain the type, etc.)

Comment: When I just print `ex` it also returns `93`.

When calling `print traceback.format_exc(ex)`, it prints `KeyError: 93`

Comment: Ok, so I'm not sure that your assertion that removing `try`/`except` means that the code no longer raises an exception. Presumably it's just coincidental and you're not getting a `KeyError` when you remove the `try`/`except`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you're doing in your try. The exception is created and raised in that code. It is possible to set an exception's message to 93, or to anything else.

Try evaluating the entire exception in your debugger, or stepping through the code you're running in try until you get the the exception, and look at the context in which it is created/raised. This will at least give you an idea of what the code/module was doing when it failed.

My guess is that the code running in try isn't well written or maintained. Try a different module, or post more details about it here.

Update:

If your stack trace is giving you KeyError, then the code you're executing is throwing a KeyError exception that isn't handled by an except block deeper down in the code, which would mean it's either poorly written or being poorly used. The issue is most likely within your 'do something'

Comment: You're right. It was a coincidence that when I ran the code previously without the Try and Except, that no exceptions were raised. I tried it again and it turned out to be an encoding issue - trying to write an unsupported unicode character into a latin-1 encoded csv file. Thanks to everyone for their help and sorry for the lack of exhaustive testing.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use smtplib.SMTP you should use Yagmail. It's easier to use:

`import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP(username, password)
yag.send(emailto, subject = "I now can send an attachment", contents = fileToSend)`